# jQuery custom string output

Tags: jquery

this is a tricky one for me so I couldn't show you any example of my own progress as i'm trying to capture a line of code that's being output by a CMS.

So the HTML on the page looks like this:

```
<h1>Location Map</h1>
<p>[ dynamic_content contact_us/directionbutton ]</p>
<p>[ google_map 74%20Ashmore%20Road%2C%20Bundall%20QLD%204217%2C%20Australia -28.01051 153.40482999999995 14 100% 300 ]</p>
<p><a href="Contact_Us">Click here</a>&nbsp;to contact us.</p>
```

I want to pull this line out:

```
74%20Ashmore%20Road%2C%20Bundall%20QLD%204217%2C%20Australia
```

Maybe by targeting "google_map"?
And then convert it to this format:

```
74+Ashmore+Road,+Bundall+QLD+4217,+Australia
```

So the "%20" becomes "+" and the "%2C" becomes "," so then I can populate the start of this script below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var startingLocation;
    var destination = "74+Ashmore+Road,+Bundall+QLD+4217,+Australia"; // replace this with any destination
```

If possible I need this to be generic for different projects where the address will be different.

I appreciate any help on this as this is way out of my jQuery comfort zone :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the correct `<p>` element:

```
var $googleMap = $('p:contains(google_map)').text();
```

then extract the location:

```
var match = $googleMap.match(/google_map\s+([^\s]+)/i);
var location = match[1];
```

then decode the location:

```
location = decodeURIComponent(location);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, because this is in a CMS, there is a chance its not always going to be inside a p tag, can you start by capturing the google_map?

Comment: You can use `$(':contains(google_map)')` to search on any tag, but keep an eye on performance, try to limit the search depth by starting from a known element: `$('#knownElement').find(':contains(google_map)')`

Comment: Thanks, ill have a play :)

Comment: Sorry I just need your help with the last section, how can I add/output "location = decodeURIComponent(location);" 
to my existing script 
"var destination = "74+Ashmore+Road,+Bundall+QLD+4217,+Australia";"

Comment: `var destination = location.replace(/\s/g, '+');`

Comment: Almost there, however im getting an error regarding this line: 
var location = match[1]; 
Error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

Comment: Sorry ignore that, it was an issue at the CMS side

Answer (score 0):

I thought you will have multiple get the elements get the t and then replace them. Worked here.

```js
$.each($('p:contains(google_map)'),function(){
  var all = $(this).text().replace(/\[|\]|google_map/g,'').split(' ');
  for(var i in all){
    if(all[i].length){
      $(this).text(decodeURIComponent(all[i]).replace(/\s+/g,'+'));
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
body>
<h1>Location Map</h1>
<p>[ dynamic_content contact_us/directionbutton ]</p>
<p>[ google_map 74%20Ashmore%20Road%2C%20Bundall%20QLD%204217%2C%20Australia -28.01051 153.40482999999995 14 100% 300 ]</p>
<p><a href="Contact_Us">Click here</a>&nbsp;to contact us.</p>
```

Cheers.

Joy

Comment: If that works, then so should `$('p:contains(google_map)').each(function() {
 var fragments = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/\[|\]|google_map/g,'').split(/\s+/);
 $(this).text(decodeURIComponent(fragments[0]));
});`.